# Is there a Bitbucket Cloud API to add member to team?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

Github has this API :
[Add or update organization membership](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-or-update-organization-membership) (given authenticated user is an organization owner)

Does Bitbucket APIs have an equivalent of this for theirs teams (equivalent of organizations in Github)?

In the docs I can see only a [read API for list members of a team](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/teams/%7Busername%7D/members) but no add member API. Does Bitbucket cloud API not support this at all?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/groups-endpoint-296093143.html#groupsEndpoint-PUTnewmemberintoagroup

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen these docs? I think this is more relevant than yours for Bitbucket. (not sure why there's two)
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html

Scroll down to the supported endpoints. I think you want "invitations, groups, group-privileges" at the top of the chart.